# react router property value

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

in the react router official [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery), there is a ModalSwitch class, with the following code

```
class ModalSwitch extends React.Component {

    previousLocation = this.props.location

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        const {location} = this.props
        if (
            nextProps.history.action !== 'POP' &&
            (!location.state || !location.state.modal)
        ) {
            this.previousLocation = this.props.location
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {location} = this.props
        const isModal = !!(
            location.state &&
            location.state.modal &&
            this.previousLocation !== location
        )
        return (
            // ...
        )
    }
}
```

1. in the first line within the class

   ```
   previousLocation = this.props.location
   ```

   why is `previousLocation` declared in this way?

   I thought I should add `const` before `previousLocation` but it is wrong because there will be syntax error, why?

   ```
   const previousLocation = this.props.location // syntax error
   ```

   Or I thought I should put `previousLocation` within `constructor` function but again it is wrong

   ```
   constructor(){
       super();
       this.previousLocation = this.props.location // this.props would be undefined, why?
   }
   ```
2. the second question would be: is the value of `this.props` the same within the following places?

   ```
   previousLocation = this.props.location

   componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {...}

   render(){...}
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1. Because `previousLocation` is the property of the class, so no const required. I think they are using `transform-class-properties` plugin. See [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

The ES transpiler will transpile the code to initialize the property into the class constructor.

`constructor` will receive a `props` dictionary so you need to do like following:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.previousLocation = this.props.location // this.props would be assign by super(props), in your code, props is undefined.
    this.previousLocation = props.location
}
```

For 2. The answer is yes. More accurate: all are pointed to the 'props' property of current component. In constructor, the original props passed from parent component. In 'componentWillUpdate', 'props' will be the old props before receiving update props. In render is the 'props' when rendering. When you console log this.props will have different value but the meaning is the same.

For example:

You have following code:

```
<Component property={this.state.value} />
```

And state.value is 5. Then `constructor` will be call, and then `render`. `this.props.value` will be 5.

In parent component, if the state is changed:

```
 setState({value: 6}).
```

Then `componentWillUpdate` will be called. `this.props.value` is the old props, the value is 5, `newProps.value` will be 6. Then the `props` will be updated and `render` will be called. In `render`, this.props.value is 6.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Tran, I really appreciate your help! Your answer to question 1 seems to be correct. with the answer of your question 1, i can modify the code as you did and console.log(previousLocation) and see its value. However, your answer to question 2 seems to be wrong. a quick console.log(this.props) inside constructor(), componentWillUpdate() and render() reveals different value when you navigate to different location, please verify if I am correct.

Comment: Update the answer for clarification

Comment: ok, it is clear now, i will accept your answer. the grammar could be better though.